# td-agent praser nginx log cpu 100%

Tags: ruby, json, nginx, fluentd

my english is not good ,sorry ...

these days ,i always test td-agent on AWS EC2(Amazon Linux AMI release 2014.03).
input log from nginx and output log to S3 is OK, this very good!

then i want praser log to json ,when i made the source format "nginx" ,it says

```
"  2015-03-31 00:12:24 +0800 [warn]: pattern not match: "95.218.58.120 - [2015-03-30T16:11:40+08:00] \"GET /provider.txt HTTP/1.1\" 200 726 \"-\" \"FreePP 2.9.5.159 (iPhone; iPhone OS 8.1.3; ar_SA) [65075070]\" "
```

i think mybe my nginx log is not default.then,i made regexp for this ,

```
format /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: (?<path>[^\"]*)+\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"?$/
```

and my log is:
    `178.152.203.39 - [2015-03-31T00:18:10+08:00] "GET /provider.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 726 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J`)"

restart td-agent ,td-agent logs seems OK.but no output found ,and my cpu 100%,any one can help me ? many thanks !!!

```
top - 00:26:17 up 4 days,  1:10,  2 users,  load average: 0.20, 0.35, 0.57
Tasks:  82 total,   3 running,  79 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 48.3%us,  2.2%sy,  0.0%ni, 47.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.3%hi,  1.7%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   7401596k total,  6612324k used,   789272k free,   151200k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  5911168k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                    
 4724 td-agent  20   0  222m  23m 2800 R 96.5  0.3   0:11.70 ruby                                                                                       
  473 nginx     20   0  119m  12m 1668 S  3.7  0.2   5:58.61 nginx



 2015-03-31 00:26:04 +0800 [info]: process finished code=0
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: reading config file path="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf"
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: starting fluentd-0.10.61
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-config-placeholders' version '0.3.0'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-mixin-plaintextformatter' version '0.2.6'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-mongo' version '0.7.6'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-rewrite-tag-filter' version '1.4.1'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-s3' version '0.5.6'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-scribe' version '0.10.14'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td' version '0.10.26'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-td-monitoring' version '0.2.0'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluent-plugin-webhdfs' version '0.4.1'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: gem 'fluentd' version '0.10.61'
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    type tail
    format /^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: (?<path>[^\"]*)+\S*)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*) "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"?$/
    time_format %d/%b/%YT%H:%M:%S%z
    path /var/log/nginx/provider.access.log
    log_level debug
    pos_file /var/log/td-agent/access.log.pos
    tag s3.nginx.access
  </source>
  <match s3.nginx.access>
    type file
    path /var/log/td-agent/nginxAccess
    time_slice_format %Y%m%d
    time_slice_wait 10m
    format single_value
  </match>
</ROOT>
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: adding source type="tail"
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: adding match pattern="s3.nginx.access" type="file"
2015-03-31 00:26:05 +0800 [info]: following tail of /var/log/nginx/provider.access.log
```

Answer (score 0):

> restart td-agent ,td-agent logs seems OK.but no output found ,

From you configuration, you use `single_value` in file output.
`single_value` is almost for `none` parser.
If you want to use `single_value`, you should use `none` in tail input.

See format section in this article: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/out_file#format

Answer (score 0):

the regexp has some wrong，
i modify it

format /^(?[^ ]*) (?[^ ]*) [(?[^]]*)] "(?\S+) (?[^"]*)" (?[^ ]*) (?[^ ]*) "(?[^\"]*)" "(?[^\"]*)"/

the pb is sloved. thanks !